# Show convergence of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Suppose $f(x)>0$ and $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}<1$$
How to see that $\int^\infty_0f(x)dx$ converges?

I think I should use definition. $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists $M>0$ s.t. $|\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}-L|<\epsilon$ for all $x>M$ where $L<1$. But how to proceed from here to show that $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int^R_0f(x)dx$ exists? It should be easy, but haven't got the key idea.

Comment: Can you see a relation between $\int_k^{k+1} f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{k+1}^{k+2} f(x)\,dx$?

Comment: $\int^{k+1}_kf(x)>\int^{k+2}_{k+1}f(x)$. So $\int^{k+1}_kf(x)$ will converge to 0?

Comment: That's not strong enough. You need more. But the premises give you that.

Comment: I think I got it: use ratio test.

Comment: Yes, that does it.

Comment: I was a bit late to the party, as you worked it out before I finished writing my answer. I don't know what the ratio test is in this context, though. Do you think my argument works too?

Comment: Let $a_k=\int^{k+1}_kf(x)dx$, the integral is just $\sum_0^\infty a_k$ which converges because $\limsup|a_{k+1}/a_k|<1$(ratio test). I think your argument also works.

Comment: @Frank Your argument is an application of the ratio test :)

Comment: Oh, good! I have never been a fan of learning 'tests'. But as we've shown here, it would save me time if I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the limit be $L \in [0,1)$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be small enough so that again $a:=  L + \epsilon \in [0,1)$. Then by the given convergence, $\exists C>0$ such that $\forall x \geq C$

$$ f(x+1) < (L+ \epsilon)f(x) = a f(x).$$

Let $n_0$ denote the first integer after $C$. Then by induction we have that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

$$f(n_0 +k) \leq a^kf(n_0).$$

Hence, by a change of variables, we have $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ that

$$\int_{n_0+k}^{n_0+(k+1)} f(x) dx = \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x+k) dx \leq a^k \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) dx.$$

Therefore

$$\int_{n_0}^{\infty} f(x) dx \leq \int_{n_0}^{n_0+1} f(x) dx \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^k < \infty,$$

where the first inequality is justified by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Since $f$ is continuous on the compact set $[0,n_0]$, it is also integrable there.